# ratchet.js and push.js on phonegap application with backbone routing

Tags: cordova, backbone.js, ratchet, push.js

I would like to use push.js for simulate a native transition on my phonegap application.
I use backbone.js, zepto.js, ratchet.js, push.js no working when i change page.

- main.js:

  ```
  require.config({
         paths: {
         jquery: 'libs/zepto/zepto-min',
         ratchet: 'libs/ratchet/ratchet-min',
         push: 'libs/ratchet/push',
         underscore: 'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
         Backbone: 'libs/backbone/backbone-min',
         order: 'libs/require/order-1.0.5',
         async: 'libs/require/async',
         utils: 'libs/utils/utils',
         text: 'libs/require/text',
         templates: '../templates'
         },
         shim: {
         'jquery': {
         exports: '$'
         },
         'underscore': {
         exports: '_'
         },
         'backbone': {
         deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
         exports: 'Backbone'  //attaches "Backbone" to the window object
         }
         }
         });


  require([
           'order!jquery',
           'order!ratchet',
           'order!push',
           'underscore',
           'Backbone',
           'router',
           'utils'

           ], function($, ratchet, push, _, Backbone, AppRouter, utils) {
          });
  ```
- router.js:

  ```
  define([
  'jquery',
  'ratchet',
  'underscore',
  'Backbone',

  'views/index/IndexView',
  'views/prova/ProvaView'

  ], function($, ratchet, _, Backbone, IndexView, ProvaView ) {

  var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
                                     routes: {
                                     "" : "index",
                                     "prova" : "prova"
                                     },

                                     index: function () {
                                     window.addEventListener('push', function(){
                                                             console.log("push event occurred")
                                                             });
                                     var indexView = new IndexView();
                                     indexView.render();

                                     },

                                     prova: function () {
                                     window.addEventListener('push', function(){
                                                             console.log("push event occurred")
                                                             });
                                     var provaView = new ProvaView();
                                     provaView.render();

                                     }
                                     });

   new Router();

   Backbone.history.start();
   });
  ```
- indexView.js/provaView.js :

  ```
   define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'Backbone',
  'text!templates/index/indexTemplate.html' //provaTemplate.html
  ], function($, _, Backbone, indexTemplate){

  var IndexView = Backbone.View.extend({
                                      events: {
                                      "touchend #prova": "prova",
                                      "touchend #back": "back"

                                      },
                                      el: $('#app'),

                                      render: function(){

                                      var that = this;

                                      this.$el.html(indexTemplate);

                                      },
                                      prova: function(event) {
                                      Backbone.history.navigate("prova", {
                                                                trigger: true
                                                                });
                                      },
                                      back: function(event) {
                                      window.history.back();
                                                                                  }

                                      });

  return IndexView;

  });
  ```

-index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ratchet.css" />
    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script data-main="js/main" src="js/libs/require/require.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

-indexTemplate.html:

```
 <!-- Header -->
 <header class="bar bar-nav">
  <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
 </header><!-- /Header -->

 <!-- content -->
 <div class="content">
  <div class="card">
    <ul class="table-view">
        <li class="table-view-cell">
            <a class="navigate-right" id="prova" data-transition="slide-in">
                Load new page with push
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</div><!-- /content -->
```

-provaTemplate.html

```
<!-- Header -->
<header class="bar bar-nav">
 <a class="icon icon-left-nav pull-left" id="back" data-transition="slide-out"></a>
 <a class="icon icon-compose pull-right"></a>
<h1 class="title">Pagina 2</h1>
</header><!-- /Header -->

<!-- footer -->
<div class="content">
sample
</div><!-- /content -->
```

Any idea? 
Thank's in advance (sorry for my english)